# Add the Plugins panel in the tools panel to my NetBeans Platform application

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

In the tools panel I have only the option of "Options". I want to have the option of "Plugins" too so that I can add different plugins to the application depending upon my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `Auto Update` and `Auto Update` UI modules from the Platform.

Do `Project->Properties`, select the `Libraries` category, expand the `Platform` node, you should find them there.

Rebuild your app and you should see a `Tools->Plugins` menu.